# jquery countdown remove when finished

Tags: jquery

afternoon,

I am using the following countdown for a quiz app i am writing.

```
 var count = 60;
    countdown = setInterval(function(){
    $("p.countdown").html(count + " seconds remaining!");
    if (count == 0) {
        $('#QuizQuestions').hide();
        $('#QuizFail').show();
        $('.anscountFail').html("Sorry, you ran out of time!");
    }
    count--;
    }, 1000);
```

Once all the questions have been answered, i then do

```
 $('p.countdown').remove();
```

to remove the p.countdown. My question is how come the page still goes to the fail page, even with this removed? and how can i stop the countdown if all questions have been answered?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should also clear interval:

```
clearInterval(countdown);
```